# Get all checkBox values into database

Tags: php

I have created an HTML form for check box:

```
<td>   
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="sweet"/>Sweet<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="sour"/>Sour<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="creamy"/>Creamy<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="bland"/>Bland<br />                
</td>
```

This is action code for php page:

```
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($mode); $i++)
{
    $mode[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string($mode[$i]);

    $query  = "INSERT INTO frutesdetails(fruitname,fruitcolor,seasonfrom,seasonto,fruitetaste,fruitbenefit) VALUES ('{$fruitname}', '{$category}', '{$startdate}', '{$enddate}','.$mode[$i].','{$fruitbenefit}')";   
}
$insertresults = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    ?>
```

I am getting only one value of check box not all.

Comment: checkboxes only transmit value `on` as per my experience. Do you get the value defined by the value attribute instead?

Comment: @DevZer0 — They only send `on` if you fail to provide a value.

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: why don't you use foreach? it is faster than your code. check [PHP benchmark (Reading loop)](http://www.phpbench.com/) for it. it causes in that your loop will check in every step  the size of your array.

Answer (score 5):

You have to pass the query to the database each time you go around the loop.

At the moment, you construct a query for each submitted item, but only pass the last one to the database.

Move the `mysql_query` call so it is inside the loop.

---

That said, you would be better off moving to a modern API (like PDO), constructing your query as a prepared statement before the loop beings, and then executing it with your data in the loop.

Comment: if i use mysql_query in side the loop i get all the record but not as one record

Comment: i got all the record in to different different row not in one row

Comment: Then insert all the non-colour data into the table, get the row id back, then use that row id to loop over your data and create new entries in your frutesdetails_colours [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table).

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** This has been edited to answer the question better

From your answers it appears you want to join all the mode responses together and execute a single insert query.

Incidentally:

- it is not good practise to wriite escaped values back into the same
  array as the original
- look into binding your input into mySQL statements instead of physically inserting them

Revised code:

```
foreach ($mode as $m)
{
   $emodes[] = mysql_real_escape_string($m); 
}

$emode = join( ',' , $emodes);


$query  =<<<EOF
INSERT INTO frutesdetails(fruitname,fruitcolor,seasonfrom,seasonto,fruitetaste,fruitbenefit) 
VALUES ('{$fruitname}', '{$category}',
        '{$startdate}','{$enddate}','{$emode}','{$fruitbenefit}')
EOF;
$insertresults = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 


?>
```

Comment: i got all the record in to different different row not in one row

Comment: i want to print all the records into one row

Comment: if you want to insert them in a single SQL statement, then join the mode strings together

Comment: am fresher can you tell me pls how to join ?

Comment: i am student so can you tell me pls

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()